# Call Installer base methods for multiple custom actions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-action

there is an existing visual studio setup project (MS VS Extension) that installs a Windows service via custom actions.

Now I am adding actions for populating the InstallLocation field (that is leaved empty by visual studio setup project created msi, see here: http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2010/01/setup-project-product-installlocation-in-registry-is-empty/).

There are two alternatives to incorporate these actions for me:

1. Integrate the additional actions into the existing custom actions
   implementation that install the service
2. Create separate class library for the additional actions and add them as second custom action items (this would allow re-using this class in all projects, without creating redundant code)

For (1) there would be no problem.

---

Alternative (2) is what this question is about:

Do I have to call the base.* methods in all custom actions?

I don't get it from the MSDN documentation, if the base methods relate to the specific custom action only or if they relate to the global installer action, e. g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.configuration.install.installer.install(v=vs.110).aspx

If this was described too confusing: do I have to call `System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install()` only once or for each custom action?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to reach this point, but now I was able to try it - and it works with both custom actions calling the base methods (this means the below snippets are in both custom action implementations of `Install()` and `Commit()`:

```cs
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    // custom stuff ...
}

public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.Commit(savedState);

    // custom stuff ...
}
```